# Need help counting the instances of a's, b's, c's, d's, and f's

Tags: c++

I have to count the instances of A's, B's, C's, D's and F's in the score arrays but I am lost as to how to do it.  The score1,score2 and score3 array's contain integers so I think I'll need to use an if statement to compare the scores but I am not sure how I would count that and display it. I have read my entire book and searched this site and others but can't find anything to help me.  Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int getAverage(int,int,int);
string letterGrade(int);
void getInfo();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   getInfo();
   system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void getInfo() {
   const int info = 5;
   string last[info];
   string first[info];
   int ID[info];
   int score1[info];
   int score2[info];
   int score3[info];
   for (int count = 0; count < info; count++) {
      cout << "last name\n";
      cin >> last[count];
      cout << "first name\n";
      cin >> first[count];
      cout << "enter ID\n";
      cin >> ID[count];
      cout << "enter test 1\n";
      cin >> score1[count];
      cout << "enter test 2\n";
      cin >> score2[count];
      cout << "enter test 3\n";
      cin >> score3[count];   
   }
   cout << endl;
   for (int count = 0; count < info; count++) {
      cout << last[count] 
        << setw(10) << first[count] 
        << setw(10) << ID[count] 
        << setw(10) <<score1[count]
        << setw(10) << score2[count] 
        << setw(10) << score3[count] 
        << setw(10) << getAverage(score1[count],score2[count],score3[count])
        << setw(10) << letterGrade(getAverage(score1[count],score2[count],score3[count]));
      cout << endl;
   }   
}
string letterGrade(int average) {
   string lGrade;
   if (average > 89)
      lGrade = "A";
   else if (average > 79 && average < 90)
      lGrade = "B";
    else if (average > 69 && average < 80)
      lGrade = "C";
    else if (average > 59 && average < 70)
      lGrade = "D";
    else if (average >= 0 && average < 60)
      lGrade = "F";
    return lGrade;
}

int getAverage(int score1,int score2,int score3) {
   int average;
   average = ((score1 + score2 + score3)/ 3);
   return average;
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your problem. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your indentation is off, and you aren't telling us what your particular problem is. I'm not seeing anything glaringly wrong either.

Comment: It sounds like your problem isn't c++ but you don't understand how to go about doing what you desire to do.

My biggest hint to you would be to not do anything other than collect information in `getInfo` function, have a separate `analyzeGrades` function.

Also since you said this c++ not c, consider making use of that fact

Comment: Micheal Hagar showed me what I was looking for.  I just needed a way to count the number of A's, B's, C's, D's and F's in the score1, score2, and score3 arrays.

Comment: You don't need all those elses. Or if you want them, then you don't need the second half of each condition. Consider 85. It fails the first if, passes the second. But 95 passes the first if and skips the second because of the else, so you don't need the `average < 90` part.

Comment: I am new to programming UpAndAdam so I am not exactly sure how to ask the question.  And I am in a C++ class and I am doing the best I can.  Honestly I have no idea how to do all of what I did in one function but I'd sure love to know.  This is an online class I have to do to graduate.  I am not a programming major so cut me a little slack.

Comment: The people commenting here are only trying to help you improve your code, you can delete `&& average < 90`, `&& average < 80`, etc. from your code as it does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
int gradeCounts[5]; 

// ..

    if (average > 89) {
        lGrade = "A";
        gradeCounts[0] = gradeCounts[0] + 1;
    } else if (average > 79 && average < 90){
        lGrade = "B";
        gradeCounts[1] = gradeCounts[1] + 1;
    } else if (average > 69 && average < 80){
        lGrade = "C";
        gradeCounts[2] = gradeCounts[2] + 1;
    } else if (average > 59 && average < 70){
        lGrade = "D";
        gradeCounts[3] = gradeCounts[3] + 1;
    } else if (average >= 0 && average < 60){
        lGrade = "F";
        gradeCounts[4] = gradeCounts[4] + 1;
    }
    return lGrade;
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks.  I had to seem dense but how would I display the count of  As, Bs, Cs, Ds, and Fs?

Comment: It is not a good idea to have side effects in a conversion function. This thing is supposed to convert 85 to B, and the work of counting the Bs belongs elsewhere in my opinion.

Comment: Ok that sounds good but my problem is I don't know how to do that.  How and where do I count the B's and other letter grades?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100 percent certain what you're trying to do, but I would say to just make variables for numAs, numBs, numCs, numDs, and numFs and set them all equal to 0 before the second for loop. Then increment the number appropriately whenever letterGrade is called, like so:

```
int numAs = 0, numBs = 0, numCs = 0, numDs = 0, numFs = 0;

// ..

if (average > 89){
    lGrade = "A";
    numAs++;
}
else if (average > 79 && average < 90){
    lGrade = "B";
    numBs++;
}
else if (average > 69 && average < 80){
    lGrade = "C";
    numCs++;
}
else if (average > 59 && average < 70){
    lGrade = "D";
    numDs++;
}
else if (average >= 0 && average < 60){
    lGrade = "F";
    numFs++;
}
return lGrade;

// ..
```

Then after that for loop, just cout the grades:

```
cout << "Number of As: " << numAs << endl;
cout << "Number of Bs: " << numBs << endl;
cout << "Number of Cs: " << numCs << endl;
cout << "Number of Ds: " << numDs << endl;
cout << "Number of Fs: " << numFs << endl;
```

Comment: Each right-half of the `else if` conditions has no effect on the code logic.

Comment: Ok I will take that out but I still have the problem of getting the program to display the count.  I have tried the above code in my program but it doesn't work.  I have to display the information in the form of a table.  The code above doesn't do it in my program.

Answer (score 0):

I know your assignment is *C++* and my (partial) answer is *C*, but I thought it might be worth sharing anyway to show you that there are different ways to achieve the same result. You might be interested in adapting my `letter_grade()` function, for example, which uses a common “premature return” idiom rather than a sequence of `if-else if-else`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N_SCORES (100)

char letter_grade(int score) {
    if(score > 100 || score < 0) {
        return (char)0;
    }

    if(score > 85) return 'A';
    if(score > 70) return 'B';
    if(score > 55) return 'C';
    if(score > 40) return 'D';
    return 'F';
}

int main(void) {
    int histogram['F'-'A'+1] = {0};
    char letter;
    int score;

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<N_SCORES; i++) {
        score  = rand() % 101;
        letter = letter_grade( score );
        if( letter == 0 ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Ignored invalid score (%d)\n", score);
            continue;
        }
        histogram[ letter - 'A' ]++;
    }

    for(letter='A'; letter<='F'; letter++) {
        if( letter=='E' )
            continue;
        printf("Number of %c grades: %2d\n", letter, 
               histogram[letter-'A']);
    }
    return 0;
}
```